# Can AppleScript take output of shell script and put in paste buffer?

Tags: shell, applescript

Can [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) take the output of a shell script or variable and put it in the paste buffer?

I have a file with a password for every day (formatted "date,password") and I want to write a script that when run will look up the date and output the password for that date.

That part is not a problem, I'm just wondering if there is a way to get the output to automatically go into the paste buffer?

Answer (score 4):

Using AppleScript to put output of a shell command into the clipboard:

```
set the clipboard to (do shell script "ls")
```

If you do not want to use AppleScript you can use `pbcopy` in the shell:

```
 sh$ some command | pbcopy
```